# Flask base route

Tags: python, web-services, rest, flask, server

I want to create rest api for my app with Flask. Is It possible to run flask with base route fe. 
localhost:5000/**webservice** that

```
@app.route('/users')
```

will handle localhost:5000/webservice/users?

Comment: Look at flask blueprints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Flask blueprints. When registering the blueprint you can add a url prefix.

```
app.register_blueprint(restapi, url_prefix='/webservice')
```

Here is a link to the flask blueprint docs:
[Flask Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/)